# 301 redirect category/category/index.php to category/category.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I am bashing my head against the keyboard, can't figure this one out and can't get the answer on google.

I have a bunch of old urls I want to 301 redirect. For example parent/child**/index.php** must become parent**/child.html**

This is what I have written:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.php$ $1.html? [L,R=301]
```

There is no request sent to the index.php so that's why I made the second condition empty. 
If I test this on [this Rewrite rule tester](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) it fails, except if I fill the request_URI value manually (see link above)

I will greatly appreciate any help with this. If I can't solve it, I would have to manually do `Redirect 301 oldurl newurl` and that's going to take a long time!

Comment: I need to add, this is for a joomla 2.5 migration, so the /administrator/index.php must still function properly

Comment: Seems to work using the *rewrite rule tester* you linked to. What is wrong? Consider posting the remainder of your `.htaccess` directives, there might be a problem with the execution order of the rules.